# Getting parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in php?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, parse-error

I am trying to insert **serialize** values into `ac_services` table but getting error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in C:\wamp\www\db-setup\steps\db-install-script.php on line 559

```
$insert_ac_services = "

INSERT INTO `ac_services` 
( `id` , `name` , `desc` , `duration` , `unit` , `paddingtime` , `cost` , `capacity` , `availability` , `business_id` , `category_id` , `staff_id` ) 
VALUES 
( 1, 'Default', 'this is default service.', 30, 'minute', 10, 15, 1, 'yes', 0, 0, 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"1";}' ) ;
";

mysql_query($insert_ac_services);
```

I generated this php query by phpmyadmin. But not working, Any suggestion? Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape the ".

`'a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"1\";}' ) ;`

Comment: Some-times stacker rocks. I made it and my installer completed. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), so that you don't need to escape any quotes.

```php
$insert_ac_services = <<<SQL

INSERT INTO `ac_services` 
( `id` , `name` , `desc` , `duration` , `unit` , `paddingtime` , `cost` , `capacity` , `availability` , `business_id` , `category_id` , `staff_id` ) 
VALUES 
( 1, 'Default', 'this is default service.', 30, 'minute', 10, 15, 1, 'yes', 0, 0, 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"1";}' ) ;
SQL;
```

That way, you can paste any query in from php_my_admin without having to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

In your last field, you insert `a:1:{i:0;s:2:"1";}`. `"` is already open, and you close it here.

You should escape the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, in my case it was a silly typo error

```
retun 0; //r is missing in return
```

Was getting the same error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER)